# Pipeline script to upload build(apk) to hockeyApp

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, hockeyapp

I am using Jenkins to build my android app. i added "Jenkinsfile" in my repo and my current pipeline script looks like this and it is working fine.

```
node
    {
        try {
            stage("build.clone")
            {
                checkout scm
            }
            stage("build.clean")
            {
                sh "./gradlew clean"
            }
            stage("build.package")
            {
                sh "./gradlew assembleDebug"
            }
        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }
```

Now i need to upload my apk to hockeyapp. HockeyApp's Jenkins plugin is installed. And they have made it compatible with pipeline in [v 1.2.2](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HockeyApp+Plugin)

I have googled a lot but found not much help. Kindly guide me or point me to  how I can use pipeline script to upload apk to hockeyapp.

**Note:** I have already created an app on hockey app and I have app token and app id. Also i know curl command is available but i want to use hockeyapp plugin with pipeline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to get the syntax for just about any Pipeline step via the [snippet generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator) built in to Jenkins.

Doing so in my Jenkins install gives me something like this (horrifying) syntax:

```
step([$class: 'HockeyappRecorder',
     applications: [[downloadAllowed: false, mandatory: false, 
     notifyTeam: false, releaseNotesMethod: [$class: 'NoReleaseNotes'],
     uploadMethod: [$class: 'AppCreation', publicPage: false]]],
     debugMode: false, failGracefully: false])
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing towards snippet generator. I found it under "simple build step" . yayyyy

Comment: I am getting this error:- `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins1687564692506600558.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `[$class:`

Comment: @pkc456 This is (old) Jenkins scripted pipeline syntax, not something you should execute as a shell script.

Comment: Can you help me to find the latest jenkin shell script